# Python/Django using python-instagram (400) APISubscriptionError-Unable to reach callback URL

Tags: python, django, instagram

Things used to work. Then it started working occasionally, until it totally stopped working.

Following is my subscription code:

```
def instagram_realtime_subscribe(event_slug, topic):
    api = InstagramAPI(client_id = CLIENT_ID, client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET)

    r = api.create_subscription(object = 'tag',
                            object_id = topic,
                            aspect = 'media',
                            callback_url = 'http://<domain>/event/%s/import/instagram/realtime'%(event_slug),
                            client_id = CLIENT_ID,
                            client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
)
```

Following is my view for handling the GET and POST requests from instagram:

```
def import_instagram_rt(request, slug):
    if request.method == "GET":
        mode = request.GET.get("hub.mode")
        challenge = request.GET.get("hub.challenge")
        verify_token = request.GET.get("hub.verify_token")
        if challenge:
            return HttpResponse(challenge, mimetype='text/html')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("test", mimetype='text/html')
    else:
        x_hub_signature=''
        if request.META.has_key('HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE'):
            x_hub_signature = request.META['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE']
        raw_response = request.raw_post_data
        data = simplejson.loads(raw_response)
        for update in data:
            fetch_data(slug, update["object_id"])
```

Following is my urls.py

```
url(r'^event/([-\w]+)/import/instagram/realtime$', import_instagram_rt),
```

This is used to work beautifully. However, it stopped working since two days. Whenever the subscription function is called, it throws the error:

```
>>> instagram_realtime_subscribe("cats", "cats")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/django-projects/imports/views.py", line 687, in instagram_realtime_subscribe
    client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/django-projects/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 151, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/django-projects/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 143, in execute
    content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/django-projects/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 124, in _do_api_request
    raise InstagramAPIError(status_code, content_obj['meta']['error_type'], content_obj['meta']['error_message'])
InstagramAPIError: (400) APISubscriptionError-Unable to reach callback URL "http://<domain>/event/cats/import/instagram/realtime".
```

I tried hitting the Callback URL manually and got the response "test" which is what you would expect from the function I have written. I tried a requests.get() manually to that url before calling the subscription function and that returned a 200 response.

Why can't Instagram find my callback url when everyone else can access it?

Comment: What was your callback's response for Instagram?

Comment: @Messa For Instagram's GET request, my function responds back with the "challenge" parameter in their GET request. You can see that from the import_instagram_rt function from above. However, that function is not being invoked at all.

Comment: I think it's not called because they're "Unable to reach callback URL". The gradual breakdown can point at something network related. Firewalls, DNS, maybe? You say the function doesn't get called, but do you see a connection TCP connection coming in?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, this had nothing to do with the code part of things. When I tried the exact same code after two days, it worked perfectly fine. Hence, I assume that this problem occurred due to being blacklisted/rate-limited for some reason. I am unaware of how the rate-limiting works for the Instagram Real time API. I will post that as a new question and link to it here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it shouldn't work like this. I'd expect a 429 response on your request. Or a 503, but certainly not with a text complaining they can't reach *you*!

Comment: Yes, that is what one would expect. However, what has happened seems to suggest that it indeed had something to do with rate limiting.

Comment: Nope.. If they were rate-limiting you, you [*would* get a decent error](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/instagram/bind.py#L94). You did succeed in contacting them and the response contained the error *they* got, which they report back by putting it in the [error](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/instagram/bind.py#L124) they raise.

Comment: I should have gotten a decent error. However, I cannot seem to find any other explanation. It slowly stopped working, then completely stopped working and then when I had given up and tried if after two days, it just worked. I had left the code intact. I did go through their code to see what you've pointed at. Anyway, it is resolved now.

Answer (score 2):

I think `import_instagram_rt` is not called because they're "Unable to reach callback URL".

Let's break down what happens when they try to reach your callback URL.

#### They parse the URL

Is your URL well-formed? `http://<domain>/event/cats/import/instagram/realtime` isn't but I think you're hiding the real hostname. ;-)

#### They resolve the hostname

Is your DNS ok? Have you done any updates to your zone and messed up the serial? Are the zone transfers between your primary and secondary servers functioning? "working occasionally", may mean that some round-robin scheme is dysfunctional or that some DNS servers give bad replies or timeout.

#### They open a TCP socket to your IP on port 80

You know the drill: [SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation). If you see something slightly off, due to some amusing hardware anomaly, consider sending it to the
[museum of broken packets](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/mobp/).

Seriously... Are all hops in your network routing these packets or are there any firewalls that may be dropping them? Do you have a "helpful" ISP that has blacklists and null-routes?

#### A process on your machine handles the connection

Do you have a process to accept the connection? If you serve using gunicorn or similar WSGI servers... do you [run it behind a reverse proxy](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html#deploying-gunicorn), that *buffers connections*? Otherwise your worker(s) may be busy with `instagram_realtime_subscribe` for your visitor, and blocking the callback call from Instagram.

#### That process responds with output

Only until this point your Django app comes into play. Routing the requestto `import_instagram_rt`, if `urls.py` is correct...

Happy hunting through logs and tcpdumps...

## PS

Why did you remove this from your question?

> My heroku log said the following:
>
> 2013-11-13T11:30:28.766021+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/instag/realtime_callback/?hub.challenge=b81d6b83b6f14fbf86015670c58e6877&hub.mode=subscribe host=ontodjangoyo.herokuapp.com fwd="54.208.187.11" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0

The status [503](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_503#5xx_Server_Error) is a strong indication that you don't have a worker available to handle the instagram request...
If you have 1 worker and the heroku proxy doesn't buffer requests, then when you "tried hitting the Callback URL manually" the one worker responds as expected. But when your django  app is handling a request and calls `instagram_realtime_subscribe`. then your worker is blocking until it gets a response from instagram, which it doesn't get, because instagram is waiting your worker to become available to handle the callback. This will wait on each other till a timeout occurs. That 503 status may be cached by the proxy for a while.

Comment: Earlier, I was trying it out for the first time and was using heroku as a test case. Lately, I implemented it on staging correctly, it worked perfectly fine, started to not work intermittently, & now does not work at all. Hence removed the heroku logs from the question. That is irrelevant.

Replace <domain> by "haris.in" as an example. That is how the url is. I tried changing the url to different formats. Nothing worked.

I don't think DNS and resolving are issues because I can hit the url perfectly fine from my browser. It responds. I also tried from other computers in other areas. It works.

Comment: I tried running directly on the Django runserver with nginx as the reverse proxy. It worked perfectly fine, until it slowly started degrading and ended up not working at all. I also tried it on gunicorn, but it did not work there either.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your TCP related questions. Will have to look into it.

Comment: @harisibrahimkv tcpdump is your friend. Capture anything not port 22 (your ssh connection) and analyse it with wireshark.